# Mousewheel and Scrollto how to stop multiple events firing

Tags: jquery, scrollto, mousewheel

I Tried out many solutions posted and can't get anything to work. I am using the jQuery mousewheel plugin to detect mousewheel events.

On a scroll event I just want to scroll to a given id using scrollTo(). I understand there are issues with events firing multiple times for each scroll and that this is why the code I have got below is not working properly, giving long delays between scrolls, if at all.

I have stripped all my attempts at timers, unbinding mousewheel event etc. and just left in the basic functionality I need! The scrollTo() works fine for click events so everything else is OK.

```
//scrollTo on mousewheel event

$(window).mousewheel(function() {
   $.scrollTo( '#home-top', 350, {easing:'swing'});
});
```

Some help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you are trying to snap to a nearby id when scrolling, right? My advice is not to over-ride standard scrolling behaviour. As a user if I want to view something I expect to click or scroll to get there, not to scroll and be taken. Also, it's not great to bind to the scroll event as it fires so often, but the good news is most scrollwheels scroll in increments of 10 or 20 px so it's not that bad.

Comment: Thanks Dean. Unfortunately, I am bound by my clients request, they saw a feature on another site and this is what they want. 

Get your point about binding to events (in this case mousewheel) and I am definitely looking for a better solution.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle in the original post with a test-case, and someone can take a look. You can add the jquery mousewheel plugin by just linking to the raw file on github :)

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Not used jsfiddle - I'll have a fiddle!

Comment: @RichardMoger have you found a solution for this? I am in a similar situation now.